# Send value from input via url PHP - JS

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server

I want to send the value of one input text by a link to make and insert in other page. I don't wanna use a submit type because these elements are inside a form with submit for another page.

This is my code of devices_insert.php:

```
<div class="cp_oculta" id="plus1" name="new_fabricant">
        <input type="text" id="add_fabricant" name="add_fabricant"  placeholder="New Fabricant">
        <a href="fabricants_insert.proc.php?link=<?php echo **SOLUTION** ?>" onclick="valor()">
        <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
</div>
```

I can get the value with a function but I don't know how to send it via url.

```
<script>
function valor(){
var bla = $('#add_fabricant').val();
}
</script>
```

And I pretend to send to fabricants.insert.proc.php for make the insert:

```
<?php
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO Property (PRP_PRP_TYP_Id, PRP_Value) VALUES ('2', '$_REQUEST[**SOLUTION**]')";
echo($sql_insert);
?>
```

I have checked before many solutions in stackoverflow but I think are not useful for my case.

Comment: Are you looking for an ajax-solution? Btw, be careful regarding sql injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem in a easy way:

```
<script>
function valor(){
$('#fabricant_link').attr('href', 'fabricants_insert.proc.php?new='+$('#add_fabricant').val());
}
</script>
```

Now with this script send the variable with the url and I can receive it in the other page (fabricants_insert.proc.php) for insert in the database.

```
  <div class="cp_oculta" id="plus1" name="new_fabricant">
        <input type="text" id="add_fabricant" name="add_fabricant"  placeholder="New Fabricant">
        <a onclick="valor()" id="fabricant_link">
        <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
  </div>
```

I only need to add an id to the link to use the function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use ajax, e.g.:

```
<script>
$('#add_fabricant').on('blur', function(){
    $.post(url, {
        'SOLUTION': $(this).val()
    }).done(function(rst){
        //to do
    })
})
</script>
```